# How to get data from Firebase using c# and using JSON key but not using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform

I am using Google.Cloud library for c#, and I want to get data from my Firestore database.
I want to use JSON key, but I dont want to put it to GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable.

my json Key is stored in C# variable

string jsonKey = ...;

project id is stored in other variable:

string projectId = ...;

How to do it.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you mean by "json key"? Do you mean the content of a service account credential, or the path to that as a file, or something else?

Comment: jsonKey is a string which stores full json key, not a path to json file. This json key has all informations needed to login to  Firestore database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got the full service account credential JSON in `jsonKey`, then you just need:

```cs
var firestoreDb = new FirestoreDbBuilder
{
    ProjectId = projectId,
    JsonCredentials = jsonKey
}.Build();
```

Basically each "client" type (in this case `FirestoreDb`) provides a corresponding builder class which is intended to make it easy to provide everything you need. (In the next major version, to be released fairly soon, this will also provide integration with Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.)